# Unexpected EOF while finding contacts in iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, contacts

I am building an ionic app which accesses the contacts using the apache cordova plugin contacts

I tried accessing the contacts using contacts plugin v2.0.1 with the following code

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";
options.multiple = true;

var fields = ["displayName","phoneNumbers"];

navigator.contacts.find(fields, gotContacts, errorHandler, options);
```

This throws me an `SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF` in iPhone 6s models.

I tested the same in iPhone 5s and iPhone 6, this works fine. Also it works fine in iPhone 6s Simulator.

I tested in three iPhone 6s phones where the iOS is 9.3 for two phones and 9.2.1 for one.

All three phones have contacts more than 400.

All three returned me the same error.

Am I missing something here or is there a workaround for this.?

Comment: please, report your problem on http://issues.cordova.io/

Comment: Yea.. I have already created a ticket with them. Ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11010